# Deducing parameter types from bind-expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

In order to deduce the parameter types for functional objects I have created helper classes that allow me to get the according `std::function<...>` for generic parameters. The helper classes right now look like this:

```
template<typename T>
class functional_traits : public functional_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {

};

template<typename Ret, typename ClassType, typename... Args>
class functional_traits < Ret(ClassType::*)(Args...) const > {
public:
    typedef std::function<Ret(Args...)> FunctionType;
};
```

The same version as the last exists also with a non const specialization. You can use this like that:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T& value) {
    auto function = (typename functional_traits<T>::FunctionType)(value);
}

foo([](int a) { return a * 2.3f; });
```

and you will have function as `std::function<float (int)>`. This is fine since according to the standard a lambda is required to end up as a C++ non-union class object with a member operator () that is either const or non-const (when the lambda is mutable)

So much for what is working ;)

The problem now is when I'm using `foo(std::bind(someMethod, std::placeholders::_1))`. The return type of std::bind is not specified by the standard, its not even mandatory that its featuring an `operator ()`. In Visual Studio and gcc there is such an operator but it has 4 overloads (one const volatile, one volatile, one const and one without modifiers). Now of course the `decltype(&T::operator())` fails because it doesnt know which overload I want.

I have tried using typedes to convert T into an always const volatile type and then hoping that `&T_cv::operator()` would always select the `const volatile` version of the operator, but that is not the case.

So my problem or question is: Is there a way to get the arguments of a result from `std::bind` with partial specialization? I assume the existence of an `operator ()` as given since I'm only interested in Visual Studio (and maybe a lot later gcc).

Comment: `std::function<Sig>` is a type erasure class. Type deduction and type erasure are opposing techniques. Using type deduction to determine the type of type erasure you are doing is asking about how to build a mound to install a pool. Your current plan doesn't even work with all "normal" function objects or C++14 lambdas or overloaded functions. You are barking up the wrong tree. Now, there are extremely narrow cases where such deduction is useful, but 99/100 times people try it without a good reason. Of course, 99/100 people I say this to think they are the 1/100, so... want to make your case?

Comment: It has a good reason for my use case. Its one of the many overloads used to expose a function to a scripting interface, like `Class<Foo>("Foo").function("test", [](Foo* _this, int arg) { return _this->bar * arg; })`. Since there are sometimes a lot of functions to expose i want most of it done without any of my work. There are other overloads that cover an std::function argument or `&Foo::member` or unbound functions (using SFINAE). The only thing thats not working is the same thing for `std::bind`.

Comment: Ah, reason 97!  Answer: Your interface to the scripting engine should not be deduced from how you implement it, but a fixed interface should be exposed, and the implementation bindings should be tested against that fixed interface, as implementation changes should clearly not cause interface changes.  (The punchline, that there is no way to do what you want in general, remains).  The testing of the binding against the fixed interface can be done without type deduction.  Think about the alternative -- every change to the implementation could break the interface accidentally.

Comment: so long story short: Stick to lambdas, regular functions and std::function objects because its all fine and use std::bind results like overloaded methods where you put the type parameters in the template parameters and all is fine.